# Extrude Complex SVG with React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, svg, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

By following [this CodeSandbox example by rabelais88](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-svg-logo-xlrpj?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00063b6j6mk28ftq%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00023b6j84s5i8es%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00033b6jpzd59sq6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00053b6j6up94zuf%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clq5a6m6w00023b6j84s5i8es%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00023b6j84s5i8es%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5apzc100023b6jw4bjaryi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A41%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A7%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A55%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FLogo.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5apzc100023b6jw4bjaryi%2522%257D%252C%2522clq5a6m6w00053b6j6up94zuf%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00043b6j1e2dr3kz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00053b6j6up94zuf%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00043b6j1e2dr3kz%2522%257D%252C%2522clq5a6m6w00033b6jpzd59sq6%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clq5a6m6w00033b6jpzd59sq6%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D), it's possible to extrude an SVG with React Three Fiber.

However, when I try doing it with [the more complex tiger SVG Three.js has as an example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=svg#webgl_loader_svg), I get nothing back. No error message, and nothing on the screen. Does anyone know what's going on? (Some tips on how to debug this would be useful as well, I guess...)

The only thing that's different from rabelais88's example seems to be that the [tiger SVG](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/models/svg/tiger.svg) has more groups (`<g>`), other than that, I don't know why it doesn't work. And the tiger SVG also has different colors, which I don't think it's something rabelais88's code accounts for. However, shouldn't then the tiger appear extruded with one color?

Here's a copy of rabelais88's code pretty much, just for reference — in order to reproduce it in the sandbox, just upload the tiger SVG and then change the file in the `useLoader` —:

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

import * as THREE from "three";
import { SVGLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/Addons.js";
import { Canvas, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

function Logo() {
  const svgData = useLoader(SVGLoader, "tiger.svg");
  const shapes = useMemo(() => {
    return svgData.paths.map((p) => p.toShapes(true));
  }, [svgData]);

  return (
    <mesh
      scale={0.05}
      rotation={[1 * Math.PI, 0, 0]}
      position={[-0.7, 0.5, 0]}
    >
      {shapes.map((s, i) => (
        <extrudeGeometry
          key={i}
          args={[
            s,
            {
              depth: 1,
              bevelEnabled: false,
              steps: 30,
            },
          ]}
        />
      ))}
      <meshPhongMaterial
        color="red"
        side={THREE.DoubleSide}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
}

export default function Svg() {
  return (
    <main style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
      <Canvas>
        <OrbitControls />
        <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <spotLight
          intensity={0.5}
          position={[300, 300, 4000]}
        />

        <Logo />
      </Canvas>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's quite an interesting topic. It seems to me that all the extruded geometries used the same material. I tried with simple shapes like a square or circle and there was no problem. The problem arose with the multiplicity of paths.
All extruded geometries were placed in the same parent `<mesh>` component, with no individualy positioning.
This lack of separation made it difficult to distinguish between different paths, especially if they overlapped.
The extrusion `depth` was set to `1` for all geometries, set to `0.1` made difrence. Depending on the size and scale of the SVG paths, this depth value might have caused overlap or made the paths difficult to discern. On the beginning all paths was red from original svg so I tried make each extruded geometry now has its own `<meshPhongMaterial>` component with the color taken from the original SVG data `{svgData.paths[i].color}`. And seems works.

```
import { MeshProps, useLoader } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import * as T from "three";
import { SVGLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/SVGLoader";

const Logo = (props: MeshProps) => {
  const svgData = useLoader(SVGLoader, "/lvup_icon.svg");
  const shapes = useMemo(() => {
    return svgData.paths.map((p) => p.toShapes(true));
  }, [svgData]);

  return (
    <mesh scale={0.01} rotation={[Math.PI, 0, 0]} position={[-1.7, 2.5, 0]}>
      {shapes.map((s, i) => (
        <mesh key={i} position={[0, 0, 0]}>
          <extrudeBufferGeometry
            args={[
              s,
              {
                depth: 0.1,
                bevelEnabled: false,
                steps: 30,
              },
            ]}
          />
          <meshPhongMaterial
            attach="material"
            color={svgData.paths[i].color}
            side={T.DoubleSide}
          />
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </mesh>
  );
};

export default Logo;
```

Off movement

```
import { useFrame, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";

const Camera = () => {
  const { camera } = useThree();
  // useFrame((state) => {
  //   const t = state.clock.getElapsedTime();
  //   const { mouse } = state;
  //   camera.position.y = mouse.x * 0.5;
  //   camera.position.x = Math.cos(t) * 2 + mouse.x * 0.5;
  //   camera.position.z = Math.sin(t) * 2 + mouse.y * 0.5;
  //   camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
  // });
  return null;
};
export default Camera;
```

The colors depend on the lights, but I also remember that during one of the 3js updates they tinkered with the colors, so that could be a factor too. [Here is the CodeSandbox to it](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-svg-logo-forked-m9mshm?file=%2Fsrc%2FLogo.tsx).

[image]

Comment: Could you also share your CodeSandbox fork with a link? I've tried your attempt, and it does draw the shapes, but does it really extrude the shape? It seems to have no thickness. And there's a a lot of flickering, which I think comes from z-fighting (even though it stops after a while for some reason).

Comment: https://t.ly/BJlCm

Comment: `t.ly` is apparently unreachable right now? Maybe share the direct CodeSandbox link to your fork?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/r3f-svg-logo-forked-m9mshm?file=%2Fsrc%2FLogo.tsx